# How to define custom path to MySQL socket file?

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have following config

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql-socket/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
innodb_log_file_size=16M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/shared/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

So, there is a custom path to the socket file `/var/lib/mysql-socket/mysql.sock`.

MySQL server works but I cannot connect to it.

```
$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

but needed file is exists.

```
$ ls /var/lib/mysql-socket/mysql.sock
/var/lib/mysql-socket/mysql.sock
```

When path to the socket file is `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` it works fine.

Comment: please provide result of `ps -ef | grep mysql`

Comment: I assure you, it works. :) `mysql       15     1  0 14:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your error message says it's connecting to the wrong socket:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

You can either specify that in command line:

```
mysql -S /var/lib/mysql-socket/mysql.sock ...
```

Or in the my.cnf file under the client section (this can also be in users home directory `~/.my.cnf`):

```
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql-socket/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /mysql/data/mysql/mysql.sock
#datadir                = /var/lib/mysql
datadir         = /mysql/data/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# By default we only accept connections from localhost
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
[client]
port=3306
socket=/mysql/data/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Note:

1. Do not forget to add a `[client]` section, else you will get an error:

   > ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2. Or you could pass a flag to the `mysql` command as below:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p --socket=/absolute/path/of/your/mysql.sock
   ```